# Как отправить пакет в мир?

Tags: сеть, scapy

Начал изучать scapy, и решил попробовать отправить пакет `ICMP` на `google.com` (Классика короче :D) но пакет ушел но ответа не поступило, потом решил поробовать в лоальной сети это проверить, решил пингануть модем он пингуется. В чем проблема где я ошибся ? подскажите ?

`ping = IP(dst="tplinklogin.net", ttl=45)/ICMP(type="echo-request")`

Comment: Выполнил у себя `send(IP(dst="8.8.8.8", ttl=45)/ICMP(type="echo-request"))`, запрос ушёл, ответ вернулся. Вы бы показали, как Вы отправляете пакет, и как Вы узнали, что пакет уходит, а ответ не возвращается?

Comment: @МихаилМуругов Я отправил пакет и ждал ответ командной sr1(ping)

Comment: `sr1(IP(dst="8.8.8.8", ttl=45)/ICMP(type="echo-request"))` тоже всё уходит и возвращается.